# How can I know that my DNS is slow?

Tags: dns

I read about fast connections and slow internet due to ISP's slow DNS, as a solution they recommended swithing to Google or other fast DNS.

Now, I am on 15 Mbps Internet connection and I would like to measure if my DNS is fast or slow.  How can I measure that?

Comment: @slhck - These are not duplicates... This questions asks how to measure if their DNS is fast or slow. The other asks about choosing a DNS based on many factors, not just speed of DNS. That being said, the other question has an answer that talks about [**`namebench by Google`**](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/) which should serve as a good answer to this question.

Comment: @Kevin … which is precisely why I've marked it as a duplicate. Note that the point of closing as duplicates is not "this is the same question as…" but "this question has an answer here: …"

Comment: @KevinFegan Thanks. This was the tool I was looking for.